# Practice the Beats and Tempos in Franz Liszt Consolations No. 3, Lento placido, in D♭ major, S.172

Tags: theory, piano, tempo, performance-practice, romantic-period

In Franz Liszt Consolations No. 3, Lento placido, in D♭ major, S.172,

let us call the quarter note as one beat.

Thue the eight note is 1/2 beat.

The tuplet note (hat 3) is 1/3 beat.

We see the right-hand top voice has the tempo going as 1/2 beat progression (so 8 x 1/2 =4 beats per bar),

while the left-hand bottom voice has the tempo going as 1/3 beat progression (so 12 x 1/3 =4 beats per bar).

**My question is how do we practice and play the right-hand and left-hand unmatched tempos effectively and easily? Any tips on doing this? Should we make every beat precisely mathematically? or should we play more casually in an unprecise way? **

This question should be very common to anyone who practices Chopin. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: There are *many* questions here about playing 2:3 and 4:3 on piano, but your post doesn’t indicate whether you’ve seen them or not.

Comment: Thanks I am asking for this particular Liszt. But if you have general comments/answers, please feel free to post!

Comment: Then I think its necessary to explain why this specific Liszt is different from the other 2:3, 4:3 cases.

Comment: Ok, it's Horowitz.  But I still think that performance is rhythmically incoherent.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to play the 4:3 polyrhythm section of the piano accompaniment for "Madrigal" by Gaubert?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/133664/how-to-play-the-43-polyrhythm-section-of-the-piano-accompaniment-for-madrigal)

Comment: Not covered in the duplicate: "Should I play it with mathematical precision?" No more so (or less so) than you should play any rhythm with mathematical precision in Liszt. How would you play the triplets if the 8ths weren't present, and vice versa? Do that.